# How to style divs like a table (example as attached per SharePoint)?

Tags: html, css

How can I style a group of related divs to look like a table per the attached image?  Thx!

```
 <div class="collection"
    <div class="group">
      <div class="label">Label1</div>
      <div class="value">Value1</div>
    </div>
    ... repeats n times
</div>
```

[image: Desired style output]

**Disclaimer**: This particular html output is auto-generated and I don't have control over what is generated.  I just have divs to work with and I want to style accordingly.

Comment: Just use a table. It's tabular data.

Comment: ... and even if you don't want to use a table, at least use a UL (list) since you have a list of things.

Comment: I'd love to know when it became so taboo to use tables. It's like someone got the mantra of "only use tables for tabular data" confused with "never use tables."

Comment: @ŠimeVidas It's not tabular data if there's only one record

Comment: @robertc The OP stated that the structure repeats *n* times, so there are multiple records.

Comment: @MetalFrog Yes, I don't get that either. "Never abuse tables! It's OK to abuse lists though". Why?

Comment: @MrLister How does one abuse lists?

Comment: @ŠimeVidas by trying to fit stuff in a list that fits better in a table!

Comment: Thanks for the discussion all!  This particular html output that is generated and I don't have control over what is generated.  I just have divs to work with and I want to style accordingly.

Comment: @ŠimeVidas OK, then the `label` markup should be extracted from each individual record and put in a `th`.  At the moment the structure is a repeating sequence of individual records, I still don't think it's tabular data even if there's more than one of them.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sorry guys, but, what the float?

while you all tried to proscribe what you think the OP *needs*, the answer to the question actually is

```
.collection {display:table}
.group {display:table-row}
.label, .value {display:table-cell}
```

Comment: +1, but I'd also note the browser support is IE8+. If you need more browser support go with the float method.

Comment: OK, but the OP didn't mention if support for older browsers was needed. In that case I'd use actual tables. In fact, I upvoted CoffeeRain's answer.

Comment: Yeah he didn't state the required browser support so I thought I should mention it so he can make an informed decision. And I went with the float method as an alt to your answer because he said in the comments he can't change the markup.

Comment: That's true; I also noticed that later on.

Answer (score 2):

I believe

```
.label {
  width: 200px;
  float: left;
}
```

(apart from the other styling) will do the thing for you.

Answer (score 1):

**html**

```
<div class="collection">
    <div>
      <div class="label">Label1</div>
      <div class="value">Value1</div>
    </div>
    <div>
      <div class="label">Label1</div>
      <div class="value">Value1</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

css

```
.label { float:left; width:200px; border-top:1px solid #ccc; }
.value { margin-left:200px; background:#fffced; border-top:1px solid #ccc; }
```

Code: http://jsfiddle.net/wWGG8/1/

Comment: I recommend the structure UL > LI > DIV instead of DIV > DIV > DIV.

Answer (score 1):

I would just use a table. You can read about tables in HTML [here](http://w3schools.com/html/html_tables.asp) The `<tr>` tag defines a table row. The `<td>` tag defines the table data. Each `<td>` tag is a new column.

```
<table>
<tr><td>This is the table data</td><td>This is more table data in the same row</td></tr>
<tr><td>Here is another row</td><td>This is more table data in the second row</td></tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

True, you can just use a table. That would be semantically convenient.

Nonetheless, you can stick to your current HTML structure.

Just assign the divs with classes of `label` and `value` with a width and then float them to the left.

You might also need to specify a height for the div with class `group`.